# How to select only numeric columns with `pd.read_csv()`

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to read only numeric columns with `pd.read_csv`? I know that you can select either numeric or categorical columns with `select_dtypes` like so:

```py
num_cols = df.select_dtypes(include='number')
cat_cols = df.select_dtypes(include='object')
```

It would be nice if I could do either of the above operations upon reading the CSV file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

read just 1 row( instead of the full file) to determine the schema and select the dtype using the same code as you have, then read only the columns you want using `usecols`

```
columns = pd.read_csv(file, nrows=1).select_dtypes("number").columns
df = pd.read_csv(file,usecols=columns)
```

Comment: What if row 1 is all numeric, row 2  or row 10000 not ?